# Deploying .NET 5 to IIS Server with SSL disabled

Tags: ssl, iis, .net

I am currently working on an .NET 5 & SignalR application and in localhost everything seems to be working fine. When I try to deploy it to IIS pre-production Server which doesn't have a SSL certificate configured, pages other than Login are showing the message "This site can’t provide a secure connection". In the login page from the browser console I can see that most of me javascript and css files aren't loaded with the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Also from what I can see after user logs in, the request is redirected to Https. I have removed app.UseHttpsRedirection(); from the Startup and disabled SSL in the Debug properties of the application. That seems to be a wired behavior because I used to deploy applications in .NET CORE before and didn't have these kind of problems. is there any way around this problem, except configuring an SSL certificate?

Comment: I'm failing to see how this is a .NET issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think too much about it. Since you are using it for pre-production purposes setting up a self-signed certificate would probably solve these kind of problems. Since IIS provides self signed certificates it doesn't make any sense to me not to use them.

Comment: fair enough, good way around it